# chrome 49 page size indication

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Before Chrome 49 the page size was indicated on the top right of the page when we opened DevTools, and showing real time size when we resized the window. It was very practical for responsive design.
But since Chome 49 it seems to have gone.
Now I'm wondering if it was an extension that I've added a long time ago that is not working anymore, or was it a Chrome thing?
If it's a Chrome tool how can I put it back, as I don't see the option in the options.

Page Ruler is not as practical as we need to focus on an element and can't really see the real time width/height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my answer while digging in Google.
It's a bug and will be fixed on Chrome50 https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=582421

I guess I will have to use Canary! (It works on Canary)